# NodeJS why won't my function be called inside my IF/Else statement

Tags: node.js

I have a question around node and calling a function inside of if/else statements.  Below is my situation.  I'm not sure why calling the awsCreds function works from the first IF statement, but it doesn't work when I try to invoke it from the else statement.  Does it have something to do with the fact I have an if/else inside of an else statement?

```
let cacheExpiration;
let currentTime;
let awsCredentials;

async function stsGetCallerIdentity(creds, message) {
   const stsParams = { credentials: creds };
   // Create STS service object
   const kinesis = new AWS.Kinesis(stsParams);
   const parsed_value = JSON.parse(message);
   const type = parsed_value.type;
   console.info(type);

   const message_type = {
      "transcript": process.env.TRANSCRIPT_KINESIS,
      "tone": process.env.TONE_KINESIS,
      "pitch": process.env.PITCH_KINESIS
   };
   const stream_name = message_type[type];
   console.info(stream_name);

   const params = {
      Data: Buffer.from(message),
      PartitionKey: `1111`,
      StreamName: stream_name
   };
   kinesis.putRecord(params, function(err, data) {
      if (err) console.error(err);
      else {
         console.info(JSON.stringify(data));
      }
   });
}

function awsCreds() {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const roleToAssume = {
         RoleArn: process.env.IAMRole,
         RoleSessionName: `session1`,
         DurationSeconds: 900 };

      sts.assumeRole(roleToAssume, function(err, data) {
         if (err) {
            console.error(err, err.stack);
            reject(err.stack);
         } else {
            awsCreds = {
               accessKeyId: data.Credentials.AccessKeyId,
               secretAccessKey: data.Credentials.SecretAccessKey,
               sessionToken: data.Credentials.SessionToken,
               cacheExpiration: data.Credentials.Expiration
            };
            resolve(awsCreds);
         }
      });
   });
};

webSocketClient.on(`message`, async (message) => {
try {
  currentTime = new Date();
  console.log(`currentTime`, currentTime);
  console.log(`cacheExpiration`, cacheExpiration);


          if (cacheExpiration == undefined) {
            //Calling awsCreds returns values.
           awsCredentials = await awsCreds();
           stsGetCallerIdentity(awsCredentials, message)
    
        } else {
           const minutes = (cacheExpiration.getTime() - currentTime.getTime());
           console.log(`minutes`, minutes);
           if (minutes > 60000) {
              //Do something
           stsGetCallerIdentity(awsCredentials, message)
           } else {
              
              // Calling awsCreds from here returns error 'awsCreds is      not a function'.
console.log(`Refreshing credentials`);
              awsCredentials = await awsCreds();
              stsGetCallerIdentity(awsCredentials, message)
           }
        }
       
     } catch (error) {
        console.error(`There was an error`, error);
     };
)};
```

Comment: Normally, that would work fine.  I suspect there's a problem outside of this code snippet.  Are you redefining `awsCreds` accidentally somewhere?

Comment: We need to see more code because what you say is happening will not happen with only this code.  Please show where `awsCredentials` is defined and show what the function `awsCreds()` does and show the rest of this function body.

Comment: I've added the rest of the code, I am not refefining awsCreds, I only call it twice, once initially when the cacheExiration is undefined and then when the TTL has expired in which I need to refresh the credentials.  The latter is where it is failing when the TTL has expired.  Hope this helps, and thanks again for looking at this for me.

Comment: Well I feel like an idiot in missing the obvious.  Thanks alot folks for finding out the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function is called `awsCreds`, and then you assign `awsCreds` as an object literal before you `resolve`, you need `const` in front, or don't assign at all just put the object inside resolve:

Change

```
awsCreds = {
   accessKeyId: data.Credentials.AccessKeyId,
   secretAccessKey: data.Credentials.SecretAccessKey,
   sessionToken: data.Credentials.SessionToken,
   cacheExpiration: data.Credentials.Expiration
};
resolve(awsCreds);
```

To

```
resolve({
   accessKeyId: data.Credentials.AccessKeyId,
   secretAccessKey: data.Credentials.SecretAccessKey,
   sessionToken: data.Credentials.SessionToken,
   cacheExpiration: data.Credentials.Expiration
});
```